# Where is magento register user details stored

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7, registration

I am running Magento 1.7.2. and i want to know where is magento register user details stored. actually i need, if we add a new field in registration form where the value of field was stored in database table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is list of tables where user detail is stored.

```
| customer_address_entity          |
| customer_address_entity_datetime |
| customer_address_entity_decimal  |
| customer_address_entity_int      |
| customer_address_entity_text     |
| customer_address_entity_varchar  |
| customer_entity                  |
| customer_entity_datetime         |
| customer_entity_decimal          |
| customer_entity_int              |
| customer_entity_text             |
| customer_entity_varchar          |
```

And attributes are stored in following table

```
customer_eav_attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

The Best way of doing this by creating customer Attribute.

You can do this by following below steps :

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/sql/your_customattribute_setup/install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customattribute",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Custom Attribute",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Custom Attribute"

        ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customattribute");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'customattribute',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
//$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Your_Customattribute>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Your_Customattribute>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <resources>
      <Your_Customattribute_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Your_Customattribute</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </Your_Customattribute_setup>
      <Your_Customattribute_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </Your_Customattribute_write>
      <Your_Customattribute_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </Your_Customattribute_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Your_Customattribute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Your_Customattribute>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Your_Customattribute>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Then to retrieve or edit you use:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
$customer->getCustomattribute();
$customer->setCustomattribute($yourjson);
```